# Will I be able to see the results of the previous campaign if I start a new one?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am planning to replay a campaign (to achieve other achievements). Will I be able to see the results of the previous one?

For example, one of the achievement is: to accomplish all 29 mission while one campaign  "line" contains only 26. How could I know which missions should I pass then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achievements are carried over between playthroughs.

If you start a new campaign, no achievement data will be lost.

However, in your case specifically, it is also possible to replay the 3 missions you didn't do the first time via the battle archive available on the Hyperion's bridge.

Comment: Are you able to access the archive from the previous playthrough? Or once you start it again you can no longer play any (superior) mission until you finish the new one?

Comment: After finishing the final mission (when you're returned to the main menu), selecting "continue campaign" takes you *directly* *to* the archive.

Comment: But will I be able to complete other missions, like "Find out why Tychus Findlay is always in a Marine suite". In this topic: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11799/starcraft2-achievements/11801#11801 I get answer - yes... but I don't understand how... If In new campaign I will go directly to archive,... how can I talk to other guys? Thanks

Comment: The secret mission is also available to play through the original campaign's bridge monitor but if I recall properly you must firstly play the mission where you unlock the secret mission, then go to your bridge monitor and choose the secret mission from there.

Comment: @Raven, that's the case when you have finished the campaign, but if you start it again, I'm guessing the "continue campaign" button would take you to the new playthrough and thus, be unable to play posterior missions. That's my question.

Comment: @Budda, I update my answer in that question, there's no way to earn the achievement without re-starting the campaign

Comment: @Budda, a new campaign will not go directly to the archive. A new campaign will start a new campaign. Only if you press "continue" will you go to the archive.